# Shiny destroy observer once condition is met

Tags: r, shiny

I have an observe which looks for the presence of a file that is being generated by my shiny app. I'd like to email the user once this file is made. What I'm doing right now is

```
o <- observe({
           
            if (!file.exists(paste0(STORAGE_PATH, input$sample_id, "/out.html"))){
                invalidateLater(1000)
            } else {
                o$destroy()
                from <<- sprintf("<Analysis_Runner@%s>", Sys.info()[4])
                to <<- input$email_address
                subject <<- paste(input$sample_id, "Anslysis Status")
                message <<- "Your analysis is finished. Please return to the 
                Shiny app to see your results"
                body <<- list(paste0("Dear ", to, "\n", message))
                sendmail(from, to, subject, body)
            }
        })
```

I thought the `destroy` call would get rid of `o` but what I'm getting instead is an email once every second after the `out.html` is generated. If anyone could give some advice on how to only get this email to send 1 time it would be greatly appreciated. I've also tried some versions of `reactivepoll` which don't seem to do the trick either.

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44367004/r-shiny-destroy-observeevent)? Perhaps an observer cannot destroy itself.  But you could have another observer destroy it.

Comment: Thanks @michael-dewar. That's actually the post that got me very close to having this work. Seems my `destroy()` call should have been after the email was sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach works fine. Here is a working example:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("createfile", "Create file")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  tempFile <- reactiveVal("")
  
  observeEvent(input$createfile, {
    tmp <- tempfile()
    file.create(tmp)
    tempFile(tmp)
  })
  
  myObserver <- observe({
    if (!file.exists(tempFile())){
    print("File not existing")
    invalidateLater(1000)
    } else {
      print("File existing - destroying observer")
      # from <<- sprintf("<Analysis_Runner@%s>", Sys.info()[4])
      # to <<- input$email_address
      # subject <<- paste(input$sample_id, "Anslysis Status")
      # message <<- "Your analysis is finished. Please return to the
      #             Shiny app to see your results"
      # body <<- list(paste0("Dear ", to, "\n", message))
      # sendmail(from, to, subject, body)
      myObserver$destroy()
    }
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Maybe something is wrong with your `file.exists` condition?

Comment: Thanks @ismirsehregal. It seems the major issue with my code here was that the `destroy()` was before the email. Everything seems to work as expected now.